# IBM MQ queues files rolling over policy

Tags: ibm-mq

We are using IBM MQ and recently we faced an issue where some messages that were declared as sent to the MQ server by our client application were not consumed by our MQ consumer.
We lacked logging produced/consumed messages so we tried to check messages in MQ server log/data.

We found that messages are stored in `/var/mqm/qmgrs/MQ_MANAGER/queues/` but we didn't find there all messages in the queue file (old messages were not found)

What is the rollover policy of IBM MQ and where does old queues files go?

Comment: I noticed you never accepted an answer,  did either answer provide the information you needed?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how the queue files work. They are not rollover logs. The same space is continually overwritten as needed to store messages, but messages may not be written there at all if they can be processed through memory caches etc.

PERSISTENT messages are usually logged in files under /var/mqm/log, but there are circumstances where even that can be avoided.  Your qmgr's recovery logfile configuration (circular/linear etc) will determine whether historic information about PERSISTENT messages remains available.

NONPERSISTENT messages are never logged in those files.

Comment: "but there are circumstances where even that can be avoided", when does this happen?  Is this put to waiting getter?

Comment: Yes - put to waiting getter, both putter and getter not using syncpoint. Which you should not usually be doing given that you have chosen persistent messages for their reliability, but may happen.

Answer (score 1):

In IBM MQ messages can be either persistent or non-persistent.

If a message is persistent it will normally be written to the transactional logs (usually under `/var/mqm/log/MQ_MANAGER/active`) before a commit completes or before the PUT completes if not done under a unit of work.

If a message is non-persistent it will not be written to the transactional logs.

At this point either type of message may reside only in memory and will only be written to the queue file (usually under `/var/mqm/qmgrs/MQ_MANAGER/queues`) if it needs to offload memory or if it is persistent and a check point is taken.

If the message is consumed in a timely manner it may never be written to the queue file.

The queue file will shrink in size if space taken up by messages that are no longer needed is in use, this happens automatically and is not configurable or documented by IBM as far as I know.

Non-persistent messages generally do not survive a queue manager restart.

Transactional logs can be configured as circular or linear.  If circular the logs will be reused once they are no longer needed. If linear with automatic log management (introduced in 9.0.2) they will work similarly to circular.   If linear without automatic log management, what happens to logs that are no longer needed would be based on your own log management.

If the message is still in the transactional log you may be able to view it as described in "[Where's my message? Tool and instructions to use the MQ recovery log to find out what happened to your persistent MQ messages on distributed platforms](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/wheres-my-message-tool-and-instructions-use-mq-recovery-log-find-out-what-happened-your-persistent-mq-messages-distributed-platforms)".